# Unknown Type Errors when using functionblocks from my own library project

Tags: lib, twincat, structured-text

So I have a library project where I defined a couple of functionblocks and interfaces.
Now I want to use this library in a plc project (in the same twincat solution). So I do the whole save all, rebuild, save and install as a library spiel. If I try to declare a VAR in my MAIN it will result in unknown type errors. I have fiddled around a bit, and when I declare an interface withouth any properties or methods (in the lib) then I it does show up and can be used in the MAIN. But as soon as I add a property or method the class/FB/POU dissapears in the eyes of my MAIN...

I feel like I'm overlooking some option / atribute to help the PLC project to use the lib properly...
What am I missing here?
EDIT:
as you can see in the images, empty blocks are found, adding anything magically makes it dissapear
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDP3H.png)
[available classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWQw7.png)

EDIT 2: 
I solved my problem by copying the lib to a new solution. Something in the original project made it be broken. Why it did that is still a mystery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following steps:

- clean the solution where you programmed the library.
- right click on the project and click *check all objects*

if this is successfull, install the library again, remove it from the reference section and re-add it.
Then clean again and build all.

Comment: I did, thats how I can see that if I remove all properties and methods from an interface or block that I can use it. Although it is useless in that way :(

Comment: Post some images so it is easier to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Open the reference section and click on your AutomaticProbeExchangeLib. Post a picture of the window pls where the content of the library is shown.

Comment: I just created a similar setup as yours and had no problems..

Comment: okay, So I exported the library and tried it in a different solution. Works with no problems. I have no Idea why I broke it in the origional solution...